# Calling a function with a variable variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a function with a php variable variable. You'll see in my code in `function mainFunction()`. If it's not possible to do it this way, is there a better way to do it, that avoids any more code? I wish it would work this way.

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 1;

if ( $a == $b ) {
   $exampleFunction = 'exampleOne';
} else {
   $exampleFunction = 'exampleTwo';
}

//----------------------------------------------

mainFunction();

function mainFunction() {
global $exampleFunction;
    echo 'This is mainFunction <br>';
    $$exampleFunction();//Here's where I'm stuck.
}

function exampleOne() {
    echo 'This is example one <br>';
}

function exampleTwo() {
    echo 'This is example two <br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

A way to solve this problem would be to use PHP's call_user_func function. Here is the modified code (it also removes the global variable):

#### Code Example

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$b = 1;

// I'm just using this to hold the function name,
// to get rid of the global keyword. It will be passed
// as an argument to our mainFunction()
$exampleFunction = '';

if ($a == $b) {
    $exampleFunction = 'exampleOne';
} else {
    $exampleFunction = 'exampleTwo';
}

//----------------------------------------------

mainFunction($exampleFunction);

function mainFunction($func) {
    echo 'This is mainFunction <br>';
    // Use PHP's call_user_func. We are also checking to make sure
    // the function exists here.
    if (function_exists($func)) {
        // This will call the function.
        call_user_func($func);
    }
}

function exampleOne() {
    echo 'This is example one <br>';
}

function exampleTwo() {
    echo 'This is example two <br>';
}
```

#### Output

When I run this code, it produces the following output:

```
This is mainFunction 
This is example two
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just `$exampleFunction`, without `$$`:

```
<?php
function mainFunction() {
    global $exampleFunction;
    echo 'This is mainFunction <br>';
    $exampleFunction();
}
?>
```

See [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) of *variable functions*, not *variable variables*.

***P.S.:*** Also, I suggest `$exampleFunction` to be an [`argument`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) of `mailFunction`, rather than use `global`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
if ( $a == $b ) {
   $exampleFunction = exampleOne();
} else {
   $exampleFunction = exampleTwo();
}
```

and your functions should return like

```
function exampleOne() {
    return 'This is example one <br>';
}

function exampleTwo() {
    return 'This is example two <br>';
}
```

**OR** if you want to call them through the variable try to replace like

```
function mainFunction() {
   global $exampleFunction;
     echo 'This is mainFunction <br>';
     $exampleFunction();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `$exampleFunction();` instead of `$$exampleFunction();`

**OR**

use [call_user_func($exampleFunction)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Answer (score 1):

check this way :-

```
function mainFunction() {
global $exampleFunction;
echo 'This is mainFunction <br>';
$exampleFunction();
 }
```